# Loop through each 'required' field in form submission

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm having real trouble here. I can't wrap my brain around this!

What I want to do is submit a form after validating the email address and then each input that I have labeled with a class of 'required'. I would really appreciate someone showing me how to loop through those and only submit if each one is filled in.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.button').click(function() {
            var email = $("input.email").val();        
            var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
            if(filter.test(email)) {
                $('input.required').each(function() {
                    var name = $("input.required").val();
                    if(name != "") {
                        $('#form').submit();
                    } else {
                        $('#error').show();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            } 
            else {
                $('#error').show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why not use the validator jquery plugin? http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter out only elements that are empty, and then check the number of element that matched the filter. If any input matched the filter, you have an error and shouldn't post it. Something like this:

```
var emptyFields = $('input.required').filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() === "";
}).length;

if (emptyFields === 0) {
   $('#form').submit();
} else {
   $('#error').show();
   return false;
}
```

Comment: @doublenit You can mark the answer that was most useful to you as "accepted", by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer. Only one answer can be accepted. That will show other people, who might read this question in the future, which answer was most useful to you. Accepting answers will also make people more keen to help you in the future, as your accept-rate will be shown when you post questions in the future.

Comment: I would even add that you can use the property directly as well! `$('input[required=required]')).filter(...`

Answer (score 3):

```
    var isValid = true;  // Set the isValid to flag try initially

    $('input.required').each(function() {   // Loop thru all the elements
        var name = $("input.required").val();
        if(name != "") {  // If not empty do nothing

        } else {          
            isValid = false; // If one loop is empty set the isValid flag to false
            return false;    // Break out of .each loop 
        }
    });

    if(isValid){    // If valid submit form else show error
      $('#form').submit();
    }
    else{
       $('#error').show();
    return false;
}
```